# Propagating a Beer yeast culture towards other applications

Tags: yeast, beer

How much of an impact do yeasts strains have on their [beer] products? Is this a significant game changer?

I want to craft delicious fermented foods. Beer, bread and pizza are a few of my motives.

I have various (German) beers I absolutely love that I would like to propagate a culture of yeast from to make these foods and beverages. With the impression that these tasty beer's yeast cultures could be a factor that would reflect in the tastiness of these products.

My concerns are how much of a difference propagating such yeast strains are VS. other factors of the product's various ingredients. Mainly, Will I notice a big difference in the individual yeast cultures alone, aside from the other ingredient factors? Or does it not matter as much as the other ingredients?

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly possible, but commercially I know only two examples. One is bread that is (was) baked in Vleteren, home of the Struise Brouwers. It was made with the yeast from their Pannepot beer. The other are the pizzas at Otomat, which are baked with Duvel yeast.

Does it make a difference in both cases? I really don't know, both taste like bread and pizza.

Baker's yeast is much more optimised to feed on starches, which for beer would be transformed in the mash into sugars. Most brewing yeasts (except diastatic versions) can't feed on starches, only on sugars. So maybe rising might go better when sugar is added to the bread/pizza dough.

If you want to know if it works, I suggest first to buy a sachet of ale yeast (something like US-05), a sachet of lager yeast and a sachet of dry bread yeast and experiment with them, using one single recipe of bread to bake and substitute the yeast each time. This would give three kinds of bread that you can then compare.